# concurrency in java - how to test it?

Tags: java

I'm on Java concurrency at the moment.

I don't know how to write negative scenario test.

I need a way to make deadlocks and I need a way to see that without using synchronization
I could end up with problems like inconsistency.

What is generally best way to write some stress test code
that could show me bad results if synch is omitted?

Any code example would be really appriciated.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226779/how-to-run-concurrency-unit-test

Comment: think (write on paper) for all possibilities beforehand, rather than testing them.

Comment: you might also find the Concutest (http://www.cs.rice.edu/~mgricken/research/concutest/) framework handy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will almost certainly create a deadlock and demonstrates the classic deadlock scenario whereby two different threads acquire locks in an inconsistent order.

```
public class Main {
  private final Object lockA = new Object();
  private final Object lockB = new Object();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
  }

  public Main() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        a();
        sleep(3000L); // Add a delay here to increase chance of deadlock.
        b();
      }
    }, "Thread-A").start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // Note: Second thread acquires locks in the reverse order of the first!
        b();
        sleep(3000L); // Add a delay here to increase chance of deadlock.
        a();
      }
    }, "Thread-A").start();
  }

  private void a() {
    log("Trying to acquire lock A.");

    synchronized(lockA) {
      log("Acquired lock A.");
    }
  }

  private void b() {
    log("Trying to acquire lock B.");

    synchronized(lockB) {
      log("Acquired lock B.");
    }
  }

  private void sleep(long millis) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    }
  }

  private void log(String msg) {
    System.err.println(String.format("Thread: %s, Message: %s",
      Thread.currentThread().getName(), msg));
  }
}
```

The following code demonstrates a situation likely to create inconsistent results due to lack of concurrency control between two threads.

```
public class Main {
  // Non-volatile integer "result".
  private int i;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
  } 

  public Main() {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        countUp();
      }
    }, "Thread-1");

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        countDown();
      }
    }, "Thread-2");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    // Wait for two threads to complete.
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    // Print out result.  With correct concurrency control we expect the result to
    // be 0.  A non-zero result indicates incorrect use of concurrency.  Also note
    // that the result may vary between runs because of this.
    System.err.println("i: " + i);
  }

  private void countUp() {
    // Increment instance variable i 1000,000 times.  The variable is not marked
    // as volatile, nor is it accessed within a synchronized block and hence
    // there is no guarantee that the value of i will be reconciled back to main
    // memory following the increment.
    for (int j=0; j<1000000; ++j) {
      ++i;
    }
  }

  private void countDown() {
    // Decrement instance variable i 1000,000 times.  Same consistency problems
    // as mentioned above.
    for (int j=0; j<1000000; ++j) {
      --i;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Add .start() in thread creation and throws in Main method delcarations :)

Comment: And --j; in the countdown must be --i; (sorry, but I'm trying it for fun)

Comment: @Helios: Thanks - Made those corrections.  You have to type fast to get the points!

Comment: Guys thanx very much for tips and code you posted
as soon as i finish test i will reply here !

Comment: i'm not sure, but i think the "sleep" method should be invoked inside the synchronized block to increase the chance to generate a deadlock

Answer (score 0):

In above deadlock example. Period for deadlock is 3 second. After which lockA and lockB are released and occupied by Thread 2 and Thread 1