# Testing concurrent data structures

Tags: c, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, synchronization

How can you *practically* test a synchronized data structure (in C)?

Firing a couple of threads and have them compete for access to the structure for a while to see if anything goes wrong doesn't sound very safe.

EDIT in response to comments: I mean that there are several threads running functions that operate on the same set of data, with some kind of synchronization strategy (flags/semaphores/lock-free CAS/etc) to presumably eliminate race conditions and deadlocks. The problem is programatically testing for the correct synchronization of the workers.

Comment: You cannot synchronize data, only code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226779/how-to-run-concurrency-unit-test

Comment: @HansPassant: Presumably, the data structure has methods that are intended to be thread-safe.

Comment: Your question makes it sound as though you're setting up race conditions for fun and profit (?).  Try testing them with some kind of lock or semaphore system in place.

Comment: @JackManey: I take it to mean the opposite: the OP is using some kind of locks or semaphores, but wants to test the code to ensure that there *aren't* race conditions (or deadlocks, or other problems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No-one** really knows how to do this with 100% reliability.  [Here](http://www.usenix.org/event/osdi08/tech/full_papers/musuvathi/musuvathi.pdf) is just one example of of a testing tool to find concurrency bugs.

Comment: The paper you link to sound nice and presents an interesting ideea, but i was unable to find any link to the software they sugest using. Maybe a link would be in order?

Comment: Any chance of this or similar tool for other environments, e.g. Python?